# Rspec, gems driving me insane

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, rake

I've tried to find out the answer to this for 1 week and am totally lost. I'll try to provide as much info as I can, but keep in mind I am not even sure how to present this properly.

- *Ruby* - *2.0.0p451*
- *Rspec* - *3.0.3*
- *gem* - *2.4.1*

I am Currently trying to go through Testfirst.org's first exercise '00_hello'

When I enter rake while in the 00_hello directory I get this

```
(in /Users/AK/Desktop/ruby_master)
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1024:in `block in requires='
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1024:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1024:in `requires='
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:101:in `block in process_options_into'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:100:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:100:in `process_options_into'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `configure'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -S rspec /Users/AK/Desktop/ruby_master/00_hello/hello_spec.rb -I/Users/AK/Desktop/ruby_master/00_hello -I/Users/AK/Desktop/ruby_master/00_hello/solution -f documentation -r ./rspec_config failed
```

I have not altered anything, and am following the instructions provided. You eventual create a file named 'hello.rb' that allows the spec file to run properly. Even when I create it in the same directory, I get the same output as above.

Any insight, or help will be much appreciated. I've tried installing different things, and nothing is seeming to work.

P.S. I was also getting "rake aborted" besides the above output.

Answer (score 0):

Try running rake from the root directory, the one where `Rakefile` is located.

Comment: Thank you, dankohn. I tried your suggestion, and came to the conclusion that I was missing the spec_helper.rb file listed on the first line of my error message. Thank you for your help!